# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies are not Respecting B2C Password Protection Configuration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In order to protect B2C accounts from brute force password attacks, I followed this Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management

I'm currently experiencing these issues with custom policies and the smart lockout feature:

- The number of invalid **unique** password attempts that are allowed are inconsistent. I have it set for a threshold of 5, but it seems to be 5 or more.
- The lockout period doesn't seem to be respected. Immediately after getting locked out (see Screenshot of Account Locked Error), B2C allows me to sign in on the very next attempt, even though the configured lockout time hasn't been met.

[Screenshot of Account Locked Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZgut.png)

[Screenshot of Azure B2C Password Protection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnK19.png)

**Are there any other settings I have to configure or custom policy modifications I need to make in order for this to work properly/consistently?** I've been able to reproduce this inconsistency in 3 different Azure AD B2C tenants. The custom policies use the login-NonInteractive technical profile to complete the login. The policies that were the original starting point were pulled from the Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Stater Pack: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Threshold is inconsistent for humans, since we use a rolling window, and you might just be too slow. There is nothing else to configure other than the doc at the top of your post.

Comment: That makes sense. What about being able to sign in almost immediately after getting the error "Your account is temporarily locked to prevent unauthorized use. Try again later"? I would hope that the lockout duration should still be in place after receiving the error (and still within the time frame). I had it set to 15 minutes in one tenant, did 5 unique attempts, got the error, and was immediately able to log in (with correct credentials) after getting that error.

Comment: This is being investigated with a doc update staged.